# .htaccess not working

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, htaccess

I am trying to get .htaccess to work under Apache, but the server doesn't seem to honor it.

In httpd.conf I have:

```
AllowOverride All
```

I have restarted the server with `service httpd restart`. I have also done a `service httpd reload`.

The docs [suggest](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#troubleshoot) testing the configuration with a garbage .htaccess file. If the server succesfully reads the garbage .htaccess file, this should result in an error when retrieving a page from the directory. But I get no error, suggesting that the server is not parsing the file.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Start [here](http://www.apache.org/docs/mod/core.html#allowoverride). Within `<VirtualHost 123.456.7.89>`, you need to have
>   the following:
>
> ```
> <Directory "/host/domains/www.foobar.com">
> Options All MultiViews
> AllowOverride All
> # or AllowOverride AuthConfig
> Order allow,deny
> Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

Source: http://forums.devshed.com/apache-development-15/htaccess-not-being-accessed-8977.html

Comment: This wasn't exactly it, but I realized there was more than one 'AllowOverride' setting in httpd.conf. Fixing both did the trick.

Comment: Glad I could help then!